# regex to search multiple pattern

Tags: python-3.7

Edited my code, tried a different approach to get the desired output.
Let me know if it's correct

```
import re

pattern1 = re.compile(r'\b(ERROR)')
pattern2 = re.compile(r'^\d+-\d+-\d+')
count =0

with open('sample.txt',encoding='utf-8')as f:
for i in f:
    a= re.search(pattern1,i)
    if a:
        count = count + 1
        b = re.search(pattern2,i)
        if b:
            print(b.group(),':',a.group())

 print('Total ERROR in the logfile:',count)



***output:***
2019-11-22 : ERROR 
2019-11-22 : ERROR 
2019-11-20 : ERROR 
Total ERROR in the logfile: 3
```

***log.txt***
2019-11-22 16:46:46,985 - **main** - INFO - Starting to Wait for Files
2019-11-22 16:46:56,645 - **main** - INFO - Starting: Attempt 1 Checking for New Files
2019-11-22 16:47:46,488 - **main** - INFO - Success: Downloading the Files from Cloud Storage: Return

2019-11-22 16:48:48,180 - **main** - ERROR - Failed: Waiting for files the Files
2019-11-22 16:49:17,918 - **main** - INFO - Starting to Wait for Files
2019-11-22 16:49:32,160 - **main** - INFO - Starting: Attempt 1 Checking for New Files
2019-11-22 16:49:39,329 - **main** - WARNING - Success: Downloading the Files from Cloud Storage:

2019-11-22 16:53:30,706 - **main** - WARNING - Starting to Wait for Files
2019-11-22 16:53:48,180 - **main** - ERROR - Failed: Waiting for files the Files

2019-11-20 10:00:00,121 - **main** - ERROR - Failed: Waiting for files the Files

Comment: Which lines are you trying to match?

Comment: Ideally, the output should be
2019-11-22 ERROR
2019-11-22 ERROR
2019-11-20 ERROR

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you should be using to match error lines is:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*\bERROR\b.*$
```

Your updated script:

```
pattern1 = re.compile(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*\bERROR\b.*$')
count = 0

with open('log.txt',encoding='utf-8')as f:
for i in f:
    a = re.search(pattern1, i)
    if a:
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: Your pattern r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*\bERROR\b.*$' is not able to find the last ERROR line

Comment: The problem is not the pattern, it is with your script and how it handles the final line.